# How to get progress bar with tqdm in a for loop over directory

Tags: for-loop, python-3.6, spyder, tqdm

I am trying to conditionally load some files from a directory. I would like to have a progress bar from tqdm on the process. I currently running this:

```
loaddir = r'D:\Folder'
# loop the files in the directory
print('Data load initiated')
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(loaddir_res):
    for name in tqdm(files):
        if name.startswith('Test'):
            #do things
```

which gives

```
Data load initiated

  0%|          | 0/6723 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  0%|          | 26/6723 [00:00<00:28, 238.51it/s]
  1%|          | 47/6723 [00:00<00:31, 213.62it/s]
  1%|          | 72/6723 [00:00<00:30, 220.84it/s]
  1%|▏         | 91/6723 [00:00<00:31, 213.59it/s]
  2%|▏         | 115/6723 [00:00<00:30, 213.73it/s]
```

This has two problems:

1. When progress is updated a new line appears in my IPython console in Spyder
2. I am actually timing the loop over the files and not over the files that start with 'Test' and therefore progress and remaining time are not accurate.

However, if I try this:

```
loaddir = r'D:\Folder'
# loop the files in the directory
print('Data load initiated')
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(loaddir_res):
    for name in files:
        if tqdm(name.startswith('Test')):
            #do things
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-80-b801165d4cdb>", line 21, in <module>
    if tqdm(name.startswith('Probe')):

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I would like to have a progress bar in only one line that updates whenever the `startswith` loop is activated.

**----UPDATE----**

I also found out [here](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/78) that it can also be used like this:

```
files = [f for f in tqdm(files) if f.startswith('Test')]
```

Which allows to track progress with list comprehension by wrapping the iterable with tqdm. However in spyder this results in a separate line for each progress update.

**----UPDATE2----**
It actually works fine in spyder. Sometimes if the loop fails, it might go back to printing one line of progress update. But i haven't seen this very often after the latest updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

firstly the answer:

```
loaddir = r'D:\surfdrive\COMSOL files\Batch folder\Current batch simulation files'
# loop the files in the directory
print('Data load initiated')
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(loaddir_res):
    files = [f for f in files if f.startswith('Test')]
    for name in tqdm(files):
        #do things
```

This will work in any decent environment (including a bare terminal). The solution is to not give `tqdm` the unused filenames. You may find https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/wiki/How-to-make-a-great-Progress-Bar insightful.

Secondly the issue with multiple lines output is well-known and due to some environments being broken (https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#faq-and-known-issues) by not supporting carriage return (`\r`).

The correct links for this problem in Spyder are https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/512 and https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6172

Comment: I'd also suggest `tqdm(files, desc=subdir)`, and possibly `tqdm(os.walk(...))`

Comment: I don't understand this: *Spyder being broken by not supporting carriage return (\r)*. As you can see [here](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/commit/8b6edfa04db97ef02d275eb73beb3af6ead6d10c), carriage return **is** supported in qtconsole, which is the package used by Spyder in its consoles. So, what's the real source of the problem here?

Comment: Also, this is wrong: *Finally the link suggested by Carlos Cordoba ... is definitely unrelated*. Please read my answer with care: I only suggested the OP to open an issue in the tqdm repo.

Comment: I removed that info from your answer because it was incorrect.

Comment: @abcdaa indeed changing the files fed to tqdm solves the issue and reports the correct progress. Also, it does work in a single line (so, as expected to work) in spyder 3.2.3. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Carlos Cordoba apologies, it was Red Sparrow's link on your answer which was wrong. Up to you if you want to re-add what I wrote with the correct name :)

Comment: Regarding `\r` in Spyder I presume the OP updated to a version which does support it.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a known limitation of TQDM progress bars in Spyder. I'd recommend you to open an issue about it in its [Github repository](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues).

Answer (score 0):

Specify `position=0` and `leave=True` like this:

```
for i in tqdm(range(10), position=0, leave=True):
    # Some code
```

Or in a list comprehension:

```
nums = [i for i in tqdm(range(10), position=0, leave=True)]
```

It's worth to mention that you can set `position=0` and `leave=True` to be the default settings, so you won't need to specify them each time, like this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from functools import partial

tqdm = partial(tqdm, position=0, leave=True) # this line does the magic

# for loop
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    # Some code

# list comprehension
nums = [for i in tqdm(range(10))]
```